# Are displacements, velocities, forces etc. in the same vector space?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, classical-mechanics

When we label a diagram with vector arrows for displacement, velocity, acceleration, force etc., are these quantities all in the same vector space, or are they in separate, interacting vector spaces? Do forces perhaps 'act' on bodies in the sense of group action, as well as in the physical sense?

Comment: If, for example, displacements and forces were in the same vector space, then, by the definition of "vector space", it would make sense to add a displacement to a force.

Comment: @AndreasBlass OK, that's a useful observation. Would you say it makes sense to add an acceleration to a force, e.g. $F+a=ma+a=(m+1)a$?

Comment: No, it does not make sense to add an acceleration to a force. Also, it doesn't make sense to add a mass like $m$ and a number like $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they should be in different vector spaces. Even forces at different points don't have to belong to the same vector space. Velocities at a point belong to the tangent space at that point, and accelerations to the double tangent space.

Comment: What determines the vector space to which a force belongs?

Comment: Force is just some vector field that satisfies newton's axioms. If we are talking about point masses a force is just acceleration divided by the mass, so it tells you how much acceleration per unit mass a point does (newton's 2. Axiom). One more thing one should consider is that a vector space is given also by its  field (scalars). In physics scalars are not simply just reals, they also have physical dimensions (units) So one can't just add forces and accelerations even if they are at the same pont and seemingly same vector space.

Answer (score 2):

They are not in the same space. For instance:

- velocities are vectors in the tangent space $T_qQ$(which is a manifold) of the configuration manifold $Q$;
- momenta are in the cotangent bundle $T_{(p,q)}^*Q$;
- forces are proportional to accelerations, and hence are vectors in the tangent space of the tangent bundle $T_q(TQ)$.

If you are working on $Q=\mathbb{R}^n$ since all these different spaces can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself, it looks like  they belong to the same space. But in general for an arbitrary smooth manifold $Q$ this is not the case.